# jdbc encounters java.lang.ClassNotFoundException with jdk13.0.1

Tags: java, mysql

I am using jdk 13.0.1 on windows10 and trying to connect my local mysql 5.7.3. mysql is ready.

I put "Connector J" in JAVA_HOME/bin.

I've set JAVA_HOME, PATH, CLASSPATH variables.

here is the code.

```
import java.sql.*;

public class MysqlCon {
    public static void main(String args[]){  
    try{  
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bms","root","ubuntu");  
        //here sonoo is database name, root is username and password  
        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from tb_book");  
        while(rs.next())  
            System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+"  "+rs.getString(2)+"  "+rs.getString(3));  
        con.close();  
    }catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);}  
    } 

}
```

[image]

I've set Connector J in CLASSPATH.

[image]

## question

how to fix java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the MySQL dependency to the classpath of your project. It seems that you don't use build management tools like Maven or Gradle, so this involves finding the [JDBC driver JAR](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.18), downloading and adding the location to the Eclipse project settings.

If `Class.forName` is executed, it tries to load the specified `Driver` class via reflection. This means your code compiles, but you get problems at runtime, because the classpath does not contain the class to be loaded.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I updated my post. I've set Connector J in CLASSPATH. What am I missing?

Comment: You defined a classpath variable for the project, but I don't see the assignment to `BMS_1`. See i.e. [this description](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_add_an_extra_library_to_my_project%27s_classpath%3F) or [this one](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2016/07/eclipse-how-to-add-external-jar-into-classpath.html) on how to add an external library to the classpath.